# Displays a list of installed audio players

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dpkg

It is necessary to display a list of installed music players with the help of bash. Then, based on the list, select one of them to play music. If there is no player in the system, then you need to install it from the user.How do I implement this script?

`dpkg -l | grep "music player\|audio player"`

This command produces a lot of garbage. Yes, and not all packages should have a correct description.

`apt search package-name`

Too much trash.

Comment: This task is too general to be practical.  I'd consider checking for a number of select players instead.

Comment: What command can I do this with?

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? It's usually better to explain what you want to achive. In particular: Are you making a script that plays music? If so, require a music player of your choice to be installed, or perhaps give two-three alternatives. Or use a library. Don't try to enumerate all possible music players (you can't).

Comment: There is no ready made command to check for media players. It is easy to do in bash with an if statement, for example: `[ $(which vlc) ] && echo installed || echo not installed`. I'd suggest learning some bash first.